# Can't retrieve entity config: core/store_group

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, magento-community

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Magento 1.8.1

---

```
There has been an error processing your request

Can't retrieve entity config: core/store_group

Trace:
#0 /var/www/idfr/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(272): Mage::throwException('Can't retrieve ...')
#1 /var/www/idfr/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(284): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getTableName('core/store_grou...')
#2 /var/www/idfr/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(247): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->getTable('store_group')
#3 /var/www/idfr/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(155): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->getMainTable()
#4 /var/www/idfr/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(192): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->getMainTable()
#5 /var/www/idfr/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(135): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->_initSelect()
#6 /var/www/idfr/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1348): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->__construct(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Store_Group))
#7 /var/www/idfr/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1380): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core_resource/s...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Store_Group))
#8 /var/www/idfr/app/Mage.php(491): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getResourceModelInstance('core/store_grou...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Store_Group))
#9 /var/www/idfr/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(208): Mage::getResourceModel('core/store_grou...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Store_Group))
#10 /var/www/idfr/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(213): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getResourceCollection()
#11 /var/www/idfr/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(613): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getCollection()
#12 /var/www/idfr/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(466): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initStores()
#13 /var/www/idfr/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCurrentStore('', 'store')
#14 /var/www/idfr/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 /var/www/idfr/index.php(96): Mage::run('', 'store')
#16 {main}
```

Comment: make sure the file `app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml` exists and is readable.

Comment: Yes, that file is exist with permission 664. Is it right?

Comment: does that file contain this? https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.8/app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml#L41

Comment: Do you mean the line you highlighted? If it is, yes the file contains the tag <store_group>.

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely an issue with the `app/etc/local.xml` and `app/etc/config.xml`. Try replacing these files with some other running version of same app. This has done the trick for me every time I setup my new machine. I hope this would be helpful for others.

Answer (score 2):

**`Can't retrieve entity config: core/store_group`** error message means that default Magento configuration can not be initiated on your installation.

**Solution 1:** Check that **`app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc`** exists and is not corrupted. Check other files under **`app/code/core/Mage/Core`** or restore it from the backup or original Magento distribution.

Remove Magento cache (manually by **`rm -rf var/cache`**) and disable Compiler (if it was enabled) or simply move includes directory out.

If it does not help, then proceed with solution 2.

**Solution 2:** Download a new copy of Magento from the Magento Commerce site and unzip the file.

Open **`Magento > lib > Varien`** and copy the **`SimpleXML`** directory, then navigate through your sites on your localhost to the same location and replace the directory by pasting and overwriting.

Hope I was clear enough to answer your question.

Comment: Do note: When you've encountered this particular error, you **cannot refresh cache using Magento's own tools** (such as the script in `/shell/cleanCache.php`) because they must first bootstrap Magento to understand what cache to clear. As such, you'll **need to "refresh the cache" manually by `rm -rf var/cache`** or the equivalent command on Redis/MemCache/whatever cache backend you use.

Comment: Thanks @EricSeastrand. I have updated my answer.